# Can't load json data into D3.JS

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I've seen solutions to this years ago but I know they are out dated now, D3 has changed a bit. I am a total beginner with D3.JS so I'm trying to understand it better by playing around with it.

I have a json file called mydata.json in the same folder as my D3 file. What the json file looks like is...

```
[

    {"name": "Maria", "age": 30},
    {"name": "Fred", "age": 50},
    {"name": "Francis", "age": 12}

]
```

and what the whole file looks like along with the script D3 file looks like is...

```
<head>
    <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

<script>


       d3.json("mydata.json").then(function(data) {

        var canvas = d3.select("body").append("svg")
            .attr("width", 500)
            .attr("height", 500)

        canvas.selectAll("rect")
            .data(data)
            .enter()
                .append("rect")
                .attr("width", function (d) { return d.age * 2; })
                .attr("height", 50)
                .attr("y", function (d, i) { return i * 50;})
                .attr("fill", "blue")
    })

</script>

</body>
```

I can't spot the error with my code and not basic graph is appearing, does anyone have any suggestions?

Extra!

I did add in a console.log(data) to see what's happening and I did get this error message:

```
d3.v5.min.js:2 Fetch API cannot load file:///C:/Users/Tom/Desktop/D3.JS%20practice/mydata.json. URL scheme "file" is not supported.
t.json @ d3.v5.min.js:2
```

Comment: The documentation says to use `d3.json`, not `d3.JSON`. JavaScript is case sensitive. (https://github.com/d3/d3-fetch/blob/master/README.md#json)

Comment: Ah that hasn't made a difference for me unfortunately but let me change that!

Comment: add `console.log(data)` to see if the load callback is called, maybe you have a CORS problem, have a look in the console.

Comment: I did add it rioV8, I think there's an error with loading in the JSON file.

Comment: You need to be running a server to be able to access local files. If you have python on your computer, you can use [simpleHTTPserver / http.server](http://2ality.com/2015/10/http-server-nodejs.html)

Comment: Cheers that solved it

Answer (score 0):

I wasn't running a local server. I found a good article for doing it:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Common_questions/set_up_a_local_testing_server